# Undefined route.params when passing data between components via route.push

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

I want to pass data from a *Homepage.vue* to a *clickthru.vue*.

Upon clicking on a record in a table (in Homepage.vue)
I want to be routed to a new component (clickthru.vue).
The goal is to pass two kinds of data in two distinct ways:

**First:** I want to pass the *cve_id* as a route.query as shown below

```
/clickthru?cve_id=CVE-xxxx-xxxx
```

**Second:** I also want to pass an object as a param to render/mount on the html template of clickthru.vue. The object looks something like this:

```
{ "cve": "CVE-2022-45869", "severity": "Medium", "packages": [ { "package": "kernel", "version": "5.15.80.1", "owner": "joslobo", "detection_date": "12-03-2022", "BranchStatus": { "1.0": { "sourceBranch": "NULL", "status": "NULL", "detectedOn": "NULL", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "NULL", "qid": [ "NULL" ] }, "2.0": { "sourceBranch": "2.0", "status": "Unpatched", "detectedOn": "12-03-2022", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "11574", "qid": [ "Not Assigned" ] } } }, { "package": "kernel", "version": "5.10.155.1", "owner": "joslobo", "detection_date": "12-03-2022", "BranchStatus": { "1.0": { "sourceBranch": "1.0", "status": "Unpatched", "detectedOn": "12-03-2022", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "11573", "qid": [ "Not Assigned" ] }, "2.0": { "sourceBranch": "NULL", "status": "NULL", "detectedOn": "NULL", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "NULL", "qid": [ "NULL" ] } } } ] }
```

In my *homepage.vue*, I iterate over records/objects and display in a table format as shown:
**Homepage.vue**

```
<tbody>
    <template v-for="(cve) in backend_res">
        <template v-for="(pack_key, index) in Object.keys(cve.packages)">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span v-if="index == 0" @click.prevent="onAboutClick(cve.cve, cve.packages)">
                                        {{cve.cve}}
                    </span>
               </td>
            </tr>
       </template>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

```
methods: {
   onAboutClick(cve_id, cve_obj) {
     console.log('----> cve_id = ', cve_id)
     console.log('----> cve_obj = ', cve_obj) // cve_obj is successfully printed at this point
     this.$router.push(
        {
          name: 'clickthru',
          query: {'cve_id': cve_id},
          params: {'cve_obj': cve_obj}
        })}
```

**clickthru.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {

        props: ['cve_id', 'cve_obj'],

    data() {
        return {
            cve_id: this.$route.query.cve_id,
            cve_obj: this.$route.params.cve_obj, // cve_obj is undefined 
        };
    },
```

**main.js**

```
const routes = [
   {
        path: '/clickthru',
        name: 'clickthru',
        component: clickthru,
        props: true
    }
]
```

As can be seen below when *$route* is logged, the query is recognized successfuly, however, params is empty.

```
{ "fullPath": "/clickthru?cve_id=CVE-2022-45869", "hash": "", "query": { "cve_id": "CVE-2022-45869" }, "name": "clickthru", "path": "/clickthru", "params": {}, "matched": [ { "path": "/clickthru", "name": "clickthru", "meta": {}, "props": { "default": false }, "children": [], "instances": { "default": null }, "leaveGuards": { "Set(0)": [] }, "updateGuards": { "Set(0)": [] }, "enterCallbacks": {}, "components": { "default": { "props": [ "cve_id", "cve_obj" ], "__hmrId": "91ec59e3", "__file": "E:/ASTROLABE_FE/CBL-Mariner-CVE-Website/src/components/clickthru.vue" } } } ], "meta": {}, "href": "/clickthru?cve_id=CVE-2022-45869" }
```

I want to be able to pass the cve_obj without it being part of the url/path
Any tips as to how to do that whether via params, meta or any other way is appreciated

Comment: Passing objects as query params is not an appreciated way. If possible to get this `cve_object` data from API using `cve_id` then you should consider passing only the `cve_id` to the new route and on that route's page's mounted you should fetch that `cve_object` from the backend using `cve_id` that is passed as param. In that way, you will always have an updated `cve_object` and you only need to pass `cve_id` as a param to that new route.

Comment: An alternative can also be that you put your loop data in the state and pass only `cve_id` to the new route. On the new route's page's mounted, fetch the `cve_data` from the state by using param `cve_id`. I hope, I am clear.

Comment: @NehaSoni I prefer not to make an extra API call as the object has already been retrieved from API. I display multiple key:value pairs form that cve_obj in my Homepage.vue but I want to display the entire cve_obj in my clickthru. Homepage.vue and clickthru.vue are sibling components. Could you elaborate on your 2nd suggestion or provide link/reference as to how to do it. I haven't worked with any FE js before so my knowledge is very limited on the subject.

Comment: I posted the answer with explanation as for comments it would be so long.

Answer (score 0):

Because your goal is to send data after route to new page with the help of `route.push`, I ignored some part of your codes (like using table or `v-for` that you used in `Homepage.vue`). Here is my codes that I think could help you:

> Homepage.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div @click="onAboutClick(cveData.cve, cveData.packages)">
    some text
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    cveData: { "cve": "CVE-2022-45869", "severity": "Medium", "packages": [ { "package": "kernel", "version": "5.15.80.1", "owner": "joslobo", "detection_date": "12-03-2022", "BranchStatus": { "1.0": { "sourceBranch": "NULL", "status": "NULL", "detectedOn": "NULL", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "NULL", "qid": [ "NULL" ] }, "2.0": { "sourceBranch": "2.0", "status": "Unpatched", "detectedOn": "12-03-2022", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "11574", "qid": [ "Not Assigned" ] } } }, { "package": "kernel", "version": "5.10.155.1", "owner": "joslobo", "detection_date": "12-03-2022", "BranchStatus": { "1.0": { "sourceBranch": "1.0", "status": "Unpatched", "detectedOn": "12-03-2022", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "11573", "qid": [ "Not Assigned" ] }, "2.0": { "sourceBranch": "NULL", "status": "NULL", "detectedOn": "NULL", "patchedOn": "NULL", "firstPatchedPackageRelease": "NULL", "fixReleaseDate": "NULL", "aid": "NULL", "qid": [ "NULL" ] } } } ] }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onAboutClick: function (cve_id, cve_obj) {
      console.log('----> cve_id = ', cve_id)
      console.log('----> cve_obj = ', cve_obj) // cve_obj is successfully printed at this point
      let objData = JSON.stringify(cve_obj);
      this.$router.push(
          {
            name: 'clickthru',
            query: {'cve_id': cve_id},
            params: {'cve_obj': objData}
          }
      )
    } // end of function
  }
}
</script>
```

> clickthru.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    this is "clickthru" compo
  </div>
  <section>
    {{ cve_id }}
  </section>
  <section v-for="item in cve_obj">
    <div v-for="subItem in item">
      {{ subItem }}
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "clickthru",

  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      console.log(from);
      if (from.name == "about") {
        /* you must enter the name of your home component instead of "about", I used about page so I entered "about". You can find necessary info by seeing "console.log(from)" in your console. */
        vm.cve_obj = JSON.parse(vm.$route.params.cve_obj);
        /* We set the data to "localStorage" to retrieve it when the page refreshed on mounted hook. */
        localStorage.setItem("cveDataStore" , vm.$route.params.cve_obj);
      }
    })
  },


  data() {
    return {
      cve_id: this.$route.query.cve_id,
      cve_obj: JSON.parse('[{"message": "wrong info"}]')
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    if (this.cve_obj !== JSON.parse('[{"message": "wrong info"}]')) {
      if (localStorage.getItem("cveDataStore")) {
        this.cve_obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cveDataStore"));
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**I used ["beforeRouteEnter"](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api) hook in the `clickthru.vue` component because according to [this GitHub page](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#important-note) passing params directly may cause some errors or warnings when page is reloading. So we could store data in [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to show it to the user after reloading the page.**

According to [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location):

> When specifying params, make sure to either provide a string or number (or an array of these for repeatable params). Any other type (like undefined, false, etc) will be automatically **stringified**.

Because your `cve_obj` data is of type "object", to ensure that no problem will happen, I used `JSON.stringify` in `Homepage.vue` to convert it to a **string**. Then in the `clickthru.vue` component, I convert it back to an object with the help of **computed properties** and `JSON.parse` method.

If you use this code, you won't need to use `props: true` in the `main.js`, because you don't use **props** at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your solution but I get this warning:
```vue-router.mjs:35 [Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "cve_obj" when navigating. See https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22 for more details.``` cve_obj is still undefined.

Comment: Acc to that github page, looks like params has an undefined behavior and is advised against (anti pattern). Could you please recommend an alternative? Also I forgot to mention that Homepage.vue and clickthru.vue are sibling components.

Comment: @abadawi I updated the answer. In this way when reloading the page a "wrong info" message is shown to the user and only if the user comes from ```Homepage.vue" to "clickthru.vue" the **actual info** is shown.

Comment: @abadawi I updated again the answer, So you can show data even when page refreshes with the help of **localStorage**, without any warning.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, passing objects as query params is not an appreciated way, so there are two ways to do this-

**Approach 1-**
Pass only `cve_id` to the new route and when the new route's page is mounted, fetch the `cve_object` from the backend using this query param `cve_id`.
This approach is useful and recommended because you will always have updated data from the backend.

If you follow this approach then a few changes are necessary-

1. In Homepage.vue pass only `cve_id` to your new route-

```
methods: {
    onAboutClick(cve_id) {
        this.$router.push({
            name: "clickthru",
            query: { cve_id: cve_id },
        });
    },
},
```

2. On `clickthru.vue` mounted hook, init the API call to get `cve_data` of that id-

```
mounted() {
 // Make an API call to fetch the respected id's data
}
```

**Approach 2-**
When you receive the records (on which you are looping) in your `HomePage.vue`, save this data to your [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) state. Now, same as approach one, pass only the `cve_id` to your new route and when the new route's page is mounted, fetch the respected data from the [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) state instead of fetching from an extra API call.

If you follow this approach then the process will be like this-

1. When you get the backend response in your HomePage.vue, dump it in the state, like this-

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    records: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_RECORDS (state, backend_response) {
      // mutate state
      state.records = backend_response;
    }
  }
})
```

2. Same as approach one, you have the `cve_id` in your route query, so use it to fetch the respected `cve_object` from the state. So, on `clickthru.vue` mounted, do this-

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cve_object: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.cve_object = this.$store.state.records.find(
            (item) => item.id == this.$route.query.cve_id,
        );
    },
};
</script>
```

In this way you will have your records in the state, so you can find any single record using the query `cve_id` on any page.

**NOTE-**
I only give the idea to fetch and set data from the state. If you want to follow the second approach, just read about [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) and follow the documentation.
You can also check out this here complete guide on [how to set up Vuex in the Vue application](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5664336-create-a-web-application-with-vue-js/6536106-retrieve-data-from-vuex).